# Allowing preserveAspectRatio="none" on svg without stretching image elements within, to allow for flexible image masking

Tags: html, image, svg, aspect-ratio

I've been toying with using clipping masks on images for certain responsive layouts, but I'm getting a bit twisted up on the logic of the viewBox, preserveAspectRatio and the svg coordinate system.

Take for example:

```
<svg class="clipper" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <g>
    <clipPath id="mask">
      <polygon points="0,0 50,0 40,50 0,50 0,0" />
    </clipPath>
  </g>

  <g clip-path="url(#mask)">

    <image preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" height="50%" width="50%" xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/1400/800" />

  </g>

</svg>
```

This plots a polygonal clipping mask, a skewed quadrangle that reaches out to the halfway point of the svg element and halfway down the element. The image is inside a group, which is cropped by the mask.

I've put preserveAspectRatio="none" on the svg element, to make sure the clipping mask appears where I desire, but this causes the image to stretch.

The preserveAspectRatio logic on the svg element, appears to supersede the attribute applied to the image element, where I try to preserve and slice the aspect ratio.

If, instead, I put the "xMinYMid slice" value on the svg element instead, the image maintains its scale, but the clipping mask polygon no longer is positioned at the desired location as it is also scaling, in a manner I can't quite determine its logic.

Is there a way to preserve the co-ordinate system in the first example, but keep images from stretching? [I have laid both variants side by side for a comparison on codepen here.](http://codepen.io/mjjwatson/pen/adBOXJ)